# Are the implementations of the C++ normal_distribution and MATLAB's randn consistent?

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm using Mersenne twister in order to have consistent random values between projects in Matlab and C++. But I've not been able to get consistent normally distributed pseudo-random values when using `randn` or C++11's `normal_distribution`.

Here's the C++:

```
void main()
{
    unsigned int mersenneSeed = 1977;
    std::mt19937_64 generator; // it doesn't matter if I use the 64 or the std::mt19937
    generator.seed(mersenneSeed);
    std::normal_distribution<double> normal; // default is 0 mean and 1.0 std
    double temp = normal(generator); 
        // results 1.4404780513814264 for mt19937_64 and 1.8252033038258377 for mt19937
}
```

Here's the Matlab:

```
rng(1977) % default Matlab uses mersenne twister
randn()   % default is 0 mean and 1.0 std
```

I'm using Matlab 2013b and Visual Studio Express 2013. Am I doing something wrong with the C++11 normal distribution?

Comment: The exact mechanisms of the distributions are not specified by the standard, so their results are not guaranteed portable (let alone guaranteed portable to Matlab ;).

Comment: The seeding mechanisms for `rng` and your code are likely completely different too.

Comment: Are you creating mex code to call from Matlab? Is there a reason why you want identical outputs for the same seed values?

Comment: Also, since you're generating random variates from the normal distribution, I'm guessing that what ever is implemented for the C++11 spec doesn't use the [Ziggurat method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) that is the default in Matlab.

Comment: @horchler 2 teams are competing for which software solution will best solve a large computational problem. One team wrote their solution in Matlab and the other in C++. In testing the algorithms it would be nice to have the same data going to each in order to flush out edge cases.

Comment: @David: Then one option might be to use your C++11 code and write a [`mex`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) wrapper for it so it can also be called from Matlab. However, if random number generation is part of the performance metrics, the Matlab users may want to stick with `randn` - I've found C++11's implementation much slower. The way to get fast random variates in C/C++ (faster than Matlab last time I tested) is to implement the [Double precision SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister (dSFMT)](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html#dSFMT) and Ziggurat.

Answer (score 1):

The [Mersenne twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) by itself only produces 32-bit integer random numbers. The most likely explanation for the discrepancy you observe is the way how these uniformly distributed integers are transformed into normally distributed double-precision floating point numbers.

Since the documentation of [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) does not explain this transformation and the source code is not available (it is a built-in function), it is hard to say anything more about this without reverse-engineering. (According to Casey's comment, the same seems to hold for the C++ side of things.)

The easiest way to achieve consistency probably would be to generate random numbers in C++ *or* Matlab, save the results, and load them as needed. An alternative would be to write your own Matlab random number function in C++ as a [MEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html) (using C++'s `normal_distribution`), and use this function in Matlab instead of `randn`.